# How to regex and combine two words in perl match?

Tags: perl

I am trying to regex one value from given line and assign to  name. I am not getting the expected. Could you please suggest?

```
my line = "manager: CN=rakhi\\, test,OU=Site-SIN,OU=Accounts_user,OU=main,OU=site,";
my $ln = qq{$line};
if ($ln =~ /\(([^)]*)/) 
{
   print $1;
}
```

Expected results = trakhi

Comment: Execution of script will be aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Where has the t come from in the result? Why isn't line declared properly? Why are you matching everything that isn't a `)` even though `)` never appears in the line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in your code.

I guess you are expecting output *rakhi*, if so, try this:

```
my $line = qq{manager: CN=rakhi\\, test,OU=Site-SIN,OU=Accounts_user,OU=main,OU=site,};
if ($line =~ m/CN=(.*)\\/) 
{
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
rakhi
```